Does a .log extension file deletes older entries automatically? (Poweshell Add-Content)
I have a powershell script that creates a log file in a network share and then writes on it (also mapping network drives) whenever the user logs in, it's deployed by GPO. I created two functions to create the log and to write on it, here they are:
# Generates the log
Function New-Log{
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$Path,
    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [string]$Folder=$null,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [string]$Name,
    [Parameter(Position=3)]
    [switch]$OverWrite,
    [Parameter(Position=4)]
    [switch]$UseDate,
    [Parameter(Position=5)]
    [int]$MaxDays = 0
  )

  # New folder (Yes/No)
  if($Folder){
    $logPath = Join-Path -ChildPath $Folder -Path $Path
  }
  else{
    $logPath = $Path
  }

  # Add date to log name (Yes/No)
  if($UseDate.IsPresent){
    $logFile = "$(Get-Date -Format 'dd-MM_HH.mm.ss')_$($Name).log"
  }
  else{
    $logFile = "$Name.log"
  }
  
  # Ovewrite existing log
  if($OverWrite.IsPresent){
    $logFinal = (New-Item -Path $logPath -ItemType File -Name $logFile -Force).FullName
  }
  else{
    if(Test-Path -Path "$logPath\$logFile"){
      $logFinal = "$logPath\$logFile"
    }
    else{
      $logFinal = (New-Item -Path $logPath -ItemType File -Name $logFile -Force).FullName
    }
  }

  # Deletion after a quantity of days
  if($MaxDays -gt 0){
    if((Get-ChildItem -Path $logPath | Measure-Object).Count -gt $MaxDays){
      (Get-ChildItem -Path $logPath | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1).FullName | Remove-Item -Force
    }
  }
  return $logFinal
}

# Add log events
Function New-LogEvent{
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$File,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]$Event,
    [switch]$UseSemicolon
  )
  $FLG = Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss'
  if($UseSemicolon.IsPresent){
    Add-Content $File -Value "$FLG; $Event"
  }
  else{
    Add-Content $File -Value "$FLG - $Event"
  }
}

The log is created without using OverWrite and UseDate switches.
The problem is that when I look at the log, the older entries get deleted as new entries are written. We have more than 3000 users, so there's lots of new entries everyday, but for usage measurement purposes boss wants all in the same log. I still don't know if it's the functions fault or something related to the .log file extension or even network share permissons. The network share where the log is stored has write/read permissons for all domain users.
Do you guys know any trick on how to keep the log growing permanently?
Thanks in advance!

No, Add-Content does NOT delete older content automatically. Nor either of the functions you posted.  Something else is doing that. Something ELSE is removing the older content. Please post the code of how the two functions are called and relative context

This is the code where the log is created inside the script
`# Remote log
if(Test-Path -Path '\mydomain.com\files\IT\Repository\LogUseNetworkMapping\LogNetworkMapping.log'){
$logFileRemote = '\mydomain.com\files\IT\Repository\LogUseNetworkMapping\LogNetworkMapping.log'
}
else{
$logFileRemote = New-Log -Path '\mydomain.com\files\IT\Repository' -Folder 'LogUseNetworkMapping' -Name 'LogNetworkMapping'
}
Local log
$logFileLocal = New-Log -Path 'C:\Temp' -Folder 'NetworkMapping' -Name 'LogNetworkMapping' -MaxDays 5 -UseDate
`

This is the line that adds the event:
New-LogEvent -File $logFileRemote -Event "Start of network mapping $version"
Sorry for the wrong formatting of the code above, I'm kinda dumb when I have to format text in this comment section ‍♂️

@FrancoCanciani - if you add the code to your original question post you can format it as a block, and it's easier for other people to see when they first read your question rather than having to pick through the comments for additional relevant information...

Are you even sure it's your script truncating the log file? If it's on a public writeable share it could really be anything - perhaps an older version of your script is still deployed somewhere and uses the -OverWrite switch, or maybe one of your 3000 users has found the share location and intermittently deletes the log file for ... reasons? Identifying the pattern of deletion might help - e.g. is it when the file reaches a certain size? A certain number of lines? The same time every day? Or is it being cleared out on every single login so there's only ever one entry?

@mclayton The file doesn't get deleted or overwritten (meaning it resets to 0) the logs from yesterday where there today morning, when the script started executing today the latest entries where "moving up" older entries (I use cmtrace to view log files) and yesterday logs weren't there no more. It's as if there was a maximum ammount of lines for that file.

Nothing in anything you shared has the effect of truncating old lines. As mclayton said, it might be anything anywhere on the network. Also your code could be improved but that's a completely different topic.
